# android how to know a protocol can be handled?

Tags: android

One app in my system can handle URI like "weibo://abc", I want to start the intent using this URI. But in other machine before starting this URI I need to check if this URI can be handled correctly(without big delay), what I should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `PackageManager.queryIntentActivities()` to get the list of Activities that can handle this Intent.

The following code checks wether the intent can be handled. It is borrowed from android developers "[Can I Use This Intent?](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/can-i-use-this-intent.html)" article.

```
/**
 * Indicates whether the specified action can be used as an intent. This
 * method queries the package manager for installed packages that can
 * respond to an intent with the specified action. If no suitable package is
 * found, this method returns false.
 *
 * @param context The application's environment.
 * @param action The Intent action to check for availability.
 *
 * @return True if an Intent with the specified action can be sent and
 *         responded to, false otherwise.
 */
public static boolean isIntentAvailable(Context context, String action) {
    final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
    List<ResolveInfo> list =
            packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,
                    PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    return list.size() > 0;
}
```

use it like this:

```
if (isIntentAvailable(MyActivity.this,"weibo://abc"){
   //safe to startActivity here
} else {
   //no receiver for this activity
}
```

Comment: for this function, how can I construct the parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i'm wrong , but why could be the reason for thinking that Android can handle it automatic?!

If i'm not wrong with what you need , my answer is to **use [this](http://code.google.com/p/weibo-android-sdk/) weibo SDK for seeing if the URI is ok** , then you needn't think if Android have that support.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably go with the 'suck it and see' approach. Make the call and see what you get back. You have to handle error cases anyway, I'd add something that is triggered when there's no app available to process the intent.

Comment: Ok for the regular case, but not if you want to check it before (when you want to add a menu item only if it's handeld)